# Python change NAN to vector of zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan, fillna

I have a question in Python. I build up a paragraph vector using `doc2vec` and convert it to a times series. So I have an index which is the date and then 8 companies and for each day there is a vector of dimension 100 for each company to represent the news article. However, there are some days where there are no articles, which return `NaN` values. Now I would like to convert them to a zero vector of dimension 100.

I tried to do that using this code snippet:

```
test_df.fillna(value=np.zeros(100) , inplace = True)
```

However, that doesn't work because I can't replace the `NaN` by a list or an array. Is there away to fix this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the error you are given when trying to replace with a zero vector?

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock ValueError: invalid fill value with a <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try:

```
zeros = np.zeros(100)
series.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,np.ndarray) else zeros)
```

For an example of what this looks like (with only vectors of length 2 to keep things clear):

```
series = pd.Series({1:np.array([1,2]), 2: np.nan, 3: np.array([3,4])})
series

1    [1, 2]
2       NaN
3    [3, 4]
dtype: object

zeros = np.zeros(2)
series = series.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,np.ndarray) else zeros)
series

1        [1, 2]
2    [0.0, 0.0]
3        [3, 4]
dtype: object
```

If your data is in a DataFrame then a similar pattern with applymap should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'company_a': {1:np.array([1,2]), 2: np.nan, 3: np.array([3,4])}, 'company_b': {1:np.nan, 2: np.array([9,7]), 3: np.nan}})
df

  company_a company_b
1    [1, 2]       NaN
2       NaN    [9, 7]
3    [3, 4]       NaN

zeros = np.zeros(2)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,np.ndarray) else zeros)
df

    company_a   company_b
1      [1, 2]  [0.0, 0.0]
2  [0.0, 0.0]      [9, 7]
3      [3, 4]  [0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: thank you so much! your approach with applymap worked perfectly!

Comment: awesome! I have to admit I struggled a bit to understand your question at the start, I think perhaps you'll find the following link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  useful to assist you in creating an example for future questions!